# VirtualBox Kali Leafpad doesn't create an icon file on the desktop. Why not? (Command line ls shows the file exists in that directory)

Tags: kali-linux, usb-drive, gui, file-transfer

I'm doing Kali/Metasploitable homework for my Pentest+ course.

I don't own a printer and would like to transfer reports to usb.

As a test i created a leafpad file on the Desktop. All is good, but it didn't create an icon for the file. How do I learn/troubleshoot to create desktop icons for files so I can simply drag and drop.

ls shows the file.

I used my gmail from firefox and attached the file to a message that i emailed to myself. So i can send files from the virtual kali out to the real world.

Since i teach cybersecurity to stressed students who are used to windows, i also would like to know a GUI method to cut down on the learning curve.

Comment: Does the file exist on the desktop? have you verified with `ls`? If you are using a desktop environment like GNOME the default behavior might be to hide files on the desktop. Does your file manager show the files? You can use that to drag and drop files from one folder to another (USB device in this case). File management really is not that different compared to Windows....

Comment: @kemotep   I tried to verify that I'm using gnome. A youtube video said go to Activites Overview and type: about.      I got an error of no results found.  Is there a CLI command to show the version of GUI being used in KALI (Debian?)

Comment: When you are at the login screen, on the top right or typically around the top of the screen there should be a wrench or gear icon. That menu is for selecting your desktop session. The options should give you a clue as to what desktop environment you are logging into. The default Kali desktop environment should be GNOME unless you downloaded one of the alternate versions of Kali. Also saying that you went to an activities screen indicates to me that you are using GNOME. Either way you need go to your file browser or terminal and verify that the file exists in the location you saved it in.

Comment: i used gmail to attach the file from the desktop and mail it to myself. It also shows up in the CLI using the ls command. Youtube help tutorials mention all icons missing from the desktop under Nautilus. I do have the Favorites? bar. Firefox, Terminal, Burpsuite etc.

Comment: Is recommending that they save files not to `~/Desktop` and in a more sensible place like `~/Documents` or a custom folder like `~/Class Work` or `~/Projects`, etc a better idea for your students? I have added an answer to why _GNOME_ is not showing desktop icons, but please do consider that just using your file manager (e.g. Nautilus) might be easier than working exclusively off of the "Desktop".

Answer (score 0):

Since [GNOME v3](https://csorianognome.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/nautilus-desktop-plans/) the "Desktop" has been disabled by default. You can re-add this functionality with [a GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/). Here are some articles about how to install a GNOME extension [1](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-gnome-shell-extensions-gui-cli/) [2](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-gnome-shell-extensions-gui-cli/).

You can use `gnome-tweak-tool` and/or `gnome-shell-extensions` to quickly install and manage your various GNOME extensions.

If the files are hidden you can follow [these steps](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/files-hidden.html.en) to show "hidden" files:

> If you want to see all hidden files in a folder, go to that folder and either click the view options button in the toolbar and pick Show Hidden Files, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. You will see all hidden files, along with regular files that are not hidden.
>
> To hide these files again, either click the view options button in the toolbar and pick Show Hidden Files, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> again.

Alternatively you can just use your file manager of choice (GUI or CLI) to manage files.

Comment: cool got a new command.  gnome-shell --version.    GNOME Shell 3.30.2  Installed gnome-tweak-tool.  Searching for the tweak to enable desktop icons now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1358618/no-desktop-icons-in-kali-linux-but-files-can-be-seen-on-file-explorer